# Length of 'char* numberlist[]' in C and C++

Tags: c, visual-c++

Try to find out how to get the total number of items in char* numberlist[] in C and C++, the following is the code:

```
const char* list_of_filename[] = {"One","Two","Three","Four","Five"};
```

Answer (score 7):

The standard idiom for finding the number of elements in an array is

```
int num_items = sizeof(list_of_filename) / sizeof(list_of_filename[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
sizeof(list_of_filename) / sizeof(char*)
```

Or more generally:

```
sizeof(list_of_filename) / sizeof(list_of_filename[0])
```

Comment: Rather than duplicating the previous answer, you might suggest `sizeof(list_of_filename) / sizeof(*list_of_filename)`

Comment: I think we answered at the same time :) I personally prefer the `[0]` version, so I wouldn't feel right about editing in the other version. Feel free to edit it into your answer though - I gave you an upvote :)